# php sql search no injection

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have been trying to make a search function for my site but wanna do it securely and my script isn't working. :(
errors im getting

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/mysite/public_html/plugins/system/jumirouter/jumirouter.php on line 55 Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in /home/mysite/public_html/plugins/system/sourcerer/helper.php(552) : runtime-created function on line 22

```
<?php
$params = array(
    $_POST['search']
);
$server = "127.0.0.1\sqlexpress";
$options = array(
    "Database" => "data_user",
    "UID" => "myusername",
    "PWD" => "mypass"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = ?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);

if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt))
    {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
        {
        echo $row['name'];
        }
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Invalid password.";
    }

?>
```

Comment: what is "Not working"? what error you get?

Comment: I'm not sure if this could be the error, but looks like you are passing an `array` in place of `string`?

Comment: You should use the object oriented form of MYSQLI

Comment: Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/mysite/public_html/plugins/system/jumirouter/jumirouter.php on line 55

Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in /home/mysite/public_html/plugins/system/sourcerer/helper.php(552) : runtime-created function on line 22

Comment: `Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()` sounds like the corresponding php module is not loaded.

Comment: Also, your paths suggest you are using a unix type operating system. According to the [PHP documentation](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php) this module is only available for windows.